# Transformation constraint problem in rotation

Tags: constraints

I wanted to simulate a drawbridge motion, but the rotations are wrong. [image: Here I'm rotating along the y axis, but the bridge is rotating wrong]
Here I'm rotating along the y axis, but the bridge is rotating wrong

I want the cube's Y axis to rotate the other cube's Y axis, like in a drawbridge wheel. This [video](https://youtu.be/HtjsG_Jt_j4) shows exactly what the problem is.
Turning on extrapolate didn't help. all transformation were applied. Any help is appreciated. Blender version is 3.6 LTS
Edit: Here is the blend file:[The file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1p4PdkURWPgIq2Mlda2qy6EJ27wqD3PL_/view?usp=drive_link)

Comment: Share your file via blend-exchange.com adding the link on that page to your question so that we can see what's happening.

Comment: I've just followed your video exactly and it works precisely as it should, so there must be a setting somewhere in your file which is causing your issue.

Comment: In your video, changing the object origin leads to unapplied rotation on the object.  Why?  I have no idea, but it strikes me as buggy behavior.  This unapplied rotation means that once your object rotates in its world Y axis, which is not its local Y axis, you end up with Euler interpolation issues.  In future, would be a lot better if you could put all info regarding the problem directly on this site rather than parts on Youtube; if processes are necessary, best to include a "start" file and then completely describe steps to reproduce problem.

Comment: As John says, please share your file, hard to guess why it doesn't work

Comment: Sorry, I had to leave home after posting the question. I added a google drive link in the question. I'll follow the guidelines all of you pointed the next time I post a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you switch the *Transform Orientations* panel to *Local* you'll see the local orientation of your object, as you see it is not aligned the way you want. To fix that, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and apply the rotation.

[image]

Comment: Bless you! That did the trick. Thank you all for taking time to answer!